# Why is this sequence of equalities wrong?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, fake-proofs

If $A, B, C$ and $D$ are sets, then $(A\times B)\cup(C\times D) = (A\cup C)\times(B\cup D)$.
I managed to prove this wrong statement by using a sequence of equalities:

$$(A\times B)\cup(C\times D)\ .$$

$a,b$ element of $A\times B$ or $a,b$ element of $C\times D$.

$a$ element of $A$ and $b$ element of $B$ or $a$ element of $C$ and $b$ element of $D$.

(and now I rearranged which I suppose is wrong when dealing with ordered pairs of a cartesian product.)

$a$ element of $A$ or $a$ element of $C$ and $b$ element of $B$ or $b$ element of $D$.

$a$ element of $A\cup C$ and $b$ element of $B\cup D$.

$$(A\cup C)\times(B\cup D)$$

I know that this is wrong I would just like to know how much of it is wrong.

Comment: Please use MathJax for equations. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: The statements "a element of A and b element of B or a element of C and b element of D" and "a element of A or a element of C and b element of B or b element of D" are simply not equivalent.  If $a$ is a bird and $b$ is a fish OR $a$ is a planet and $b$ is a comet.  Does *not* mean either $a$ is a bird or a planet and $b$ is a fish or a comet.  In the first statement $a,b$ are other both animals or both celestial objects but the are both committed to being the same type of thing.  In the second, what $a$ is is completely independent of what $b$ is.

Comment: "a element of A and b element of B or a element of C and b element of D" $\not \Leftarrow \Rightarrow $ "a element of A or a element of C and b element of B or b element of D".  So $(A\times B)\cup (C\times D)\subset \not \supset  (A\cup C) \times (B\cup D)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are claiming that
$$(R\wedge S)\vee (T\wedge V) \tag{1}$$
is the same as
$$(R\vee T)\wedge (S\vee V).\tag{2}$$
This happens precisely where you guessed, where you "rearrange". (Here, $R$ stands for $a\in A$; $S$ stands for $b\in B$, $T$ stands for $a\in C$, and $V$ stands for $b\in D$.)

But that is just not true. It is true that (1) implies (2); but (2) does not imply (1).
In other words, you have an inclusion: $(A\times B)\cup (C\times D) \subseteq (A\cup C)\times (B\cup D)$. But you don't have equality.

Note that "or" distributes over "and" and vice versa. So (1) can be explicitly rewritten as
$$(R\vee T)\wedge (R\vee V)\wedge (S\vee T) \wedge (S\vee V).\tag{3}$$
Whereas (2) can be rewritten as
$$(R\wedge S)\vee (R\wedge V)\vee(T\wedge S)\vee (T\wedge V).\tag{4}$$
It should be clear that they are not equivalent. For example, (4) is true if $R$ and $V$ are true and $S$ and $T$ are false; but in that case, (3) is false because the term $(S\vee T)$ would be false in that case.

Comment: Thank you! I will have to look more in depth into this

Comment: Note:  $(R\land S)\lor (T\land V) \implies (R \lor T)\land (S\lor V)$ (because either $R$ and $S$ are both true so $R\lor T$ and $S\lor V$ are both true; or $T$ and $V$ are both true so  $R\lor T$ and $S\lor V$ are both true.)  But $(R \lor T)\land (S\lor V)\not \implies (R\land S)\lor (T\land V)$ (because we could have $R$ and $V$ both true but neither $R$ nor $S$ or vice versa).

Comment: @fleablood: That would be where I said "It is true that (1) implies (2); but (2) does not imply (1)" and gave exactly the same example to show that implication does not hold...

Answer (score 0):

You went from $(a \in A \wedge b \in B) \vee (a \in C \wedge b \in D)$ to $a \in A \vee a \in C \wedge b \in B \vee b \in D$  In the second you did not indicate where the parentheses should go, but you seem to assume you can commute and associate them arbitrarily.  That is not true.  If you have $a \in A$ and $b \in D$ the first is false and the second is true.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you have proven is that $(A\times B)\cup (C\cup D) \subset (A\cup C) \times (B\cup D)$.

......

If $(a,b) \in (A\times B)\cup (C\cup D)$ then $a\in A$ and $b \in B$ or $a\in C$ and $b \in D$.

So $a\in A$ or $a \in C$ so so $a \in A\cup C$.  And $b \in B$ or $b \in D$.  So $b\in B\cup D$.

So $(a,b) \in (A\cup C) \times (B\cup D)$.

So $(A\times B)\cup (C\cup D) \subset (A\cup C) \times (B\cup D)$. QED

======

But it is not bidirectional.

($a\in A$ and $b\in B$) OR ($a\in C$ and $b\in D$) $\implies$ ($a\in A$ or $a\in C$) and ($b \in B$ or $b\in D$).

But ($a\in A$ and $b\in B$) OR ($a\in C$ and $b\in D$) $\ne$ ($a\in A$ or $a\in C$) and ($b \in B$ or $b\in D$)

because ($a\in A$ and $b\in B$) OR ($a\in C$ and $b\in D$) $\not \Leftarrow$ ($a\in A$ or $a\in C$) and ($b \in B$ or $b\in D$).

.........

Consider $a\in A\setminus C$ and $ b\in D\setminus B$.

Then $(a,b) \in (A\cup C) \times (B\cup D)$ and it is true that $(a\in A$ or $a\in C$) [because $a \in A$].  ANd it is true that $(b\in B$ or $b \in D$) [because $b \in D$].

But it is not true that $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. [because $b \not \in B$] and it is not true that $a\in C$ and $b \in D$. [because $a \not \in C$].

And $(a,b) \not \in (A\times B)\cup (C\cup D)$ and $(A\cup C) \times (B\cup D)\not \subset (A\times B)\cup (C\cup D)$.

Comment: Thanks for this thorough answer